Vite uses environment variables at run time. How to feed ALB URL for backend URL on AWS if I want to deploy to ECS from ECR?
I have a project that is a full stack web application consisting of a frontend (vite ecs container) and backend (java spring boot ecs container). An ALB will point to the frontend, and backend. My terraform file feeds the ALB URL into the frontend's task definition as an environment variable so that it can make this connection. My containers are stored in AWS ECR. I want this to be an easy process so that I can simply build containers on my machine, and run the terraform.
My main issue is that vite uses environment variables at BUILD TIME, not RUN TIME. So when I run npm build, it injects the environment variables on my LOCAL machine into the newly created image (not correct!). I want it to use the environment variables fed into the task definition! else I have to run the deploy script, build a new image with manually updated URL, and then run deploy script again
Can I have it be so that my image is built on the docker image? Or is there a better way to pull this URL down?
I looked into this package and could not get it to work, seems to not fit this purpose: https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env
I also looked into possibly having it uploaded on nginx.conf but this seems to be a very difficult thing to figure out.
Similarly for docker-in-docker.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Seeing your "vite ecs container" Dockerfile would be helpful. Since Vite is a build tool, not a web server, your seem to be leaving out some important information about what is actually running in that docker container. I see you tagged the question with nginx, is it actually an nginx container?

Reading between the lines, it looks like this is actually an nginx container, serving a React application? If this is being served by the same load balancer as the backend, can't you have your react code simply check what the current hostname is (window.location.hostname), and use that to build the backend API URLs?

@MarkB this was the answer, thank you. I was unfamiliar with this command for React.

It's not a "command for React" it is a basic JavaScript feature of all web browsers. Has nothing to do with React.

Reading between the lines, it looks like this is actually an nginx container, serving a React application? If this is being served by the same load balancer as the backend, can't you have your react code simply check what the current hostname is (window.location.hostname), and use that to build the backend API URLs? –
Mark B
Commented 14 hours ago
